# filter is really slow on ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am displaying data from a web api in a table using an ng-repeat. I want to be able to filter that data using several different textboxes and select lists that align with the table columns (8 filters total). This table usually contains 10000+ rows. Here is how I am currently doing the filtering:

HTML:

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Multiple Filter Example</h1>
      <hr/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="ID Filter" class="form-control" ng-model="IdFilter" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Title Filter" class="form-control" ng-model="TitleFilter" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="URL Filter" class="form-control" ng-model="UrlFilter" />
      <br />
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Album ID</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>URL</th>
            <th>Thumbnail URL</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter:{id:IdFilter} | filter:{title: TitleFilter} | filter:{url: UrlFilter} ">
            <td>{{ item.albumId }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.title}}</td>
            <td>{{ item.url }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.thumbnailUrl}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.IdFilter = "";
  vm.TitleFilter = "";
  vm.UrlFilter = "";

  $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.data = response.data;
      console.log($scope.data);
    });


});
```

[plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8nl4pqYD33LX8U1hccZ6?p=preview)

As you can see the filter works but it is really really slow. Is there a better way to do this and speed it up? When typing into the filter text box there is a lag after i push a key on my keyboard.

Comment: When you are filtering such a large data set it is best to do this work on the server-side and not client side.

Comment: Well, there are 5000 rows in the table. you should try either batch a call or pagination. if you change your call(api url) to users and filter by id, its rather quick

Comment: one quick gain you can get is combining all 3 into one filter object. change your ng-model attributes to be the property on that filter object that matches the property you want to filter by.

Answer (score 0):

Each filter function iterates through your data once. So if you have 8 filters and 10,000+ rows, you're looking at 80,000+ rows iterated.

I'd recommend writing a custom filter that loops through your 10,000+ rows once and applies all 8 filters at once.

```
app.filter('uberFilter', function() {
  return function(data, filterCriteria) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
      if( passFilter(item, filterCriteria) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    }); 
    return filtered;
  }
})
```

Your filterCriteria should contain all the filter criteria

```
filterCriteria = {
    id: ...
  , title: ...
  , url: ...
}
```

passFilter() should check the item against all the filterCriteria's criteria

Your html should pass filterCriteria into the custom uberFilter

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data | uberFilter:filterCriteria">
```

This should hopefully speed things up by a factor of 8.